# Populate razor select list from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have looked through numerous examples online of populating a select list or even a html drop down list but nothing seems to be working.

code in my cshtml.cs class

```cs
        public DutyWeb_DEVContext db;
        public AddApplicationModel(DutyWeb_DEVContext db) => this.db = db;
        public List<SelectListItem> ministryItems {get;set;}

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ministryItems = db.Ministry.Select(x=>new SelectListItem{Value=x.Name,Text=x.Name}).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("------------"+ministryItems.Count);
        }
```

code in the cshtml class

```
            <input type="text" name="appName" placeholder="Enter Application Name">
            <select asp-items="Model.ministryItems">
                <option>Select Ministry</option>
            </select>
```

I keep getting the error

> Pages\AddApplication.cshtml(14,63): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Ministry Class

```
public partial class Ministry
{
    public Ministry()
    {
        Application = new HashSet<Application>();
    }

    public int MinistryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public int? Corguid { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Application> Application { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what if you change ministryItems from List<SelectListItem> to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and on your OnGet remove the ToList() ?

Comment: Still causes an error > Pages\AddApplication.cshtml(14,63): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Can you show your view model class please?

Comment: @MartinD. added the ministry class

Comment: What I don't understand is that the `ministryItems` list is in your Controller but the view refers to the `ministryItems` list in the view model. What is the the view model class of your .cshtml? `@model ...`

Comment: Sorry im still new to razor. The referenced model is AddApplicaitonModel, so anything exposed in the cshtml.cs class correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using System.Web.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering for your selectList and items that aren't the same type

Comment: Ahh when i initially searched for the SelectListItem documentation it showed it being referenced from  System.Web.MVC. Removing this using and adding using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering; fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problen is in the `asp-items` helper. It requires an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` as an argument. Even if you define a property in the model as `IEnumerable<>`, but use `ToList()`, the collection you assign to your `ministryItems` is still `List<>`, which causes an exception. To bypass it you should do

```
ministryItems = db.Ministry.Select(x=>new SelectListItem{Value=x.Name,Text=x.Name}).ToList() as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>;
```

---

I personally prefer to define a SelectList directly in the Razor page.

In the controller we have

```
ministryItems = db.Ministry.ToList();
```

and in Razor layout

```
<select asp-items="@new SelectList(Model.ministryItems, nameof(Ministry.Name), nameof(Ministry.Name))">
    <option>Select Ministry</option>
</select>
```

But this is a matter of taste actually.